# "No such file or directory" when building containter in docker. Can't seem to edit to the right path

Tags: python, mysql, docker, directory, path

For building my container.
I'm using python scripts to build and fill a mysql database. But when running the docker compose up. The python exits and I get *'python3: can't open file '/root/python_scripts/01_create_db.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'*

It keeps refering to *'/root/python_scripts/01_create_db.py'.*

I don't know where docker get that info from.

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
RUN pip install mysqlclient
RUN pip install mysql-connector-python

COPY python.sh ./
RUN chmod a+x python.sh
COPY . .

CMD [ "./python.sh"]
```

This is the python.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec python3 "01_create_db.py"
exec python3 "02_Quant_report_automated_insert.py"
exec python3 "03_Reagent_report_automated_insert.py"
exec python3 "04_Run_parameters_automated_insert.py"
exec python3 "05_Sequencing_report_automated_insert.py"
```

and this is the docker compose part with the mysql and python:

```
mysql:
        image: mariadb:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'nipt@qc'
            MYSQL_USER: 'MolBio'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'nipt@qc'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'nipt'
        volumes:
          - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
    python:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Python.Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
```

Any idea on how to look to fix this issue would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `exec python3 "./01_create_db.py"`

Comment: it's still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I inspected it via VS to get a detailed .json file.
noticed that workingdir was /root/python_scripts.

So I figured out that it was the image itself that still held an older path from previous tries. So I deleted the image and remade it. Now it refers to the new workdir in the dockerfile.